# Stop user from opening an already program using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-6.0

I want to **stop** the user from running another instance of an **already** running program/service in Windows using PowerShell.

**Eg:** I have notepad opened, then for minute's time period I want to disable the option to open notepad, since it already is running.

As of now, I can detect if the program is open or not, and if not I may have it opened for user (code attached).

```
$processName = Get-Process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ( $processName ) {
    Write-Host 'Process is already running!'
    #stop another instance of notepad to be opened, since it is already running
}
else {
    $userChoice = Read-Host 'Process is not running, should I start it? (Y/N)  '

    if ($userChoice -eq 'Y') {
        Start-Process notepad
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'No Problem!'
    }
}
```

But, how can I disable the option for the user to open another instance of the same?

Any lead for the same would be helpful.

Comment: You can't. There is no such a policy in Windows, not even in AppLocker. This can be done via application code - if you have source - by adding a mutex and check if it's acquired. Exit the program if it is, otherwise continue.

Comment: @vonPryz thanks for replying.
In that case can I somehow kind of freeze the system from opening another program for the same duration? (Like the system gets hanged)

Comment: If you don't have source for the app, you could write a small program that acts as a launcher for the actual app. The launcher then contains the mutex check. But this can be circumvented easily enough by just running the actual program. What, exactly, is your [practical use case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here?

Comment: @vonPryz could you please elaborate on the same? I'm new to PowerShell scripting.

Comment: I'll wrap up a sample about using a wrapper in Powershell. Meanwhile, [edit] the question and explain with more details about the use case. I'm pretty sure there might be much better a solution, but it depends what you [really are after](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows doesn't have such a feature that prevents launching multiple copies of an executable, you have two options:

1. poll process list every now and then. Terminate extra instances of the application
2. create a wrapper to the application and use a mutex to prevent multiple copies

The first option has its caveats. If additional copies are launched, it takes on the average half the polling interval to detect those. What's more, which of the processes are to be terminated? The eldest? The youngest? Some other criteria?

The second one can be circumvented easily by just launching the application itself.

The only real solution is to implement a single-instance feature in the application itself. Games often do this. For business software, be wary that the users will *hate* you, if there is a single reason why running multiple instances would be of use. Yes, especially if that use case [would be absurd](https://xkcd.com/763/).

As an example of a mutex-based launcher, consider the following function

```
function Test-Mutex {
    $mtx = new-object System.Threading.Mutex($false, "SingleInstanceAppLauncher")

    if(-not $mtx.WaitOne(0, $false)) {
        write-host "Mutex already acquired, will not launch second instance!"
        read-host "Any key"
        return
    }
    write-host "Running instance #1"
    read-host "Any key"
    # Do stuff
}
```

As like the solution 2 caveat, any user can work around the limit by just executing the `do suff` part. Remember, the wrapper prevents launching multiple instances of the *wrapper*, not about the *do stuff*.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I did work around as suggested by you in solution 1. That certainly does not allow another instance to get opened, however if the user tries to run the application with administrative privileges it cannot stop the application from running. Any help with the same would be cherry on cake.

Comment: @AlphaSniper Since you don't want to explain the [actual use case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676), there is no point trying to guess if there are solutions either.